# JAXB is not creating class for xsd email pattern element when compile using maven xjc

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, maven-3, xjc

I am using xsd in which i am validation email like

```
<xsd:element name="Company" type="Company"/>  
<xsd:complexType name="Company">  
    <xsd:sequence>  
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="Website" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="Email" type="EmailAddress" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="AccountStatus" type="AccountStatus" use="optional" default="Active" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="EmailAddress">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9_]+([-+.'][A-Za-z0-9_]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9_]+([-.][A-Za-z0-9_]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+([-.][A-Za-z0-9_]+)*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="AccountStatus">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Active"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Inactive"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Here is my pom.xml file that is using xjc snippet

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/schemas</schemaDirectory>
        <includeSchema>**/*.xsd</includeSchema>
        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory>
        <bindingFiles>binding.xml</bindingFiles>
        <enableIntrospection>false</enableIntrospection>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

here is my binding.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
<jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" />
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Here is the generated Company.java class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Company", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "website",
    "email"
})
public class Company {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Website")
    protected String website;
    @XmlElement(name = "Email")
    protected String email;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "AccountStatus")
    protected AccountStatus accountStatus;

    //setter and getters

}
```

See there is no email pattern applying to my email attrubute. Why ?

when i compile my code using maven compile then there is no EmailAddress.java class that apply pattern to my email attribute in Company.java. AccountStatus is also a simple type but maven creates AccountStatus.java class. Why maven is not creating EmailAddress.java class when i compile using maven ?  is there something wrong with my pattern ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`AccountStatus` is generated because the corresponding schema type is an enum.  For other simple types (i.e. ones with patterns) a class will not be generated.  There are a couple of reasons for not generating a class for the `EmailAddress` type:

1. It makes the class model unnecessarily large.
2. JAXB doesn't validate content down to that level, so having an extra generated class provides no value.
3. That value can be validated by setting an instance of `Schema` on the `Marshaller`/`Unmarshaller` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html).

Instead the property will be based on the base schema type.

Comment: Actually i am using the generated classes in a WebService. Now what is happening that when i use SOAPUI then it invalidate my request. If i change my `EmailAddress` type to `xsd:string` then everything works fine. So it means i can't use `xsd:pattern` ?

Comment: @Basit - How does SOAPUI fit in?

Comment: I am just telling you, that i am doing all this work because i am using it in a WebService. Firstly i used `xsd:string` instead of `EmailAddress`. Then i thought why can't i validate email in xsd so I used `EmailAddress`. I just showed the relevant code, otherwise my xsd is very big. I am using `xjc` to generate java classes from xsd, then I am using all the generated classes in Spring WebService. And when i go to test my WebService, then if the type is `xsd:string`, then SOAPUI sends the request, but when i use `EmailAddress`, then SOAPUI generate error that `Invalid request`

Comment: @Basit - You are getting an invalid request with the test data generated by SOAPUI?  Does SOAPUI generate the test data based on your WSDL (with your XML schema), or your Java model?

Comment: SOAPUI is generating data based on WSDL. I give my WSDL URI like `http://localhost:8080/test//service/test-api/testApi.wsdl`, when i create new SOAPUI project

Comment: @Basit - The schema in that WSDL has the pattern or not?

Comment: I think i need to use an event handler. I read this while searching `JAXB reports validation of data through events.  It uses a handler called as “ValidationEventHandler“, And this handler represent an instance of “ValidationEvent” and provides many details about the un-marshalling related issues.`

Comment: @Basit - Do you know what test data is being sent by SOAPUI?